# Multiple 'IN SELECT' and 'INSERT' under large loop gets hanged - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

There are 4 types of serivces for `Device`
And I have a set of 90,000 records in `Device` Table where i have to loop each device to find out its last success service record from different tabls and insert into single seperate table.
for less data the query is working fine but while having 90k it get execuation hanged.

I am using sequelize migartion to execuate this below script.

```
-- Inserting latest service performed date
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_DeviceLastServiceDate() RETURNS void AS
$$ 
  DECLARE device record;
  DECLARE serviceThree record;
  DECLARE serviceFour record;
  DECLARE serviceOne record;
  DECLARE serviceTwo record;
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE "LastService";
  FOR device IN SELECT "ID" FROM "Device" WHERE "DeletionDate" IS NULL
  LOOP
    -- ServiceOne
    SELECT INTO serviceOne "ID", "ExecutionDate", "ResultSuccessful" FROM "ServiceOne" 
      WHERE "DeviceID" = device."ID" AND "Revoke" = FALSE AND "DeletionDate" IS NULL
      ORDER BY "ExecutionDate" DESC, "ModificationDate" DESC 
      LIMIT 1;
    -- ServiceTwo
    SELECT INTO serviceTwo "ID", "ExecutionDate" FROM "ServiceTwo" 
      WHERE "DeviceID" = device."ID" AND "Revoke" = FALSE AND "DeletionDate" IS NULL
      ORDER BY "ExecutionDate" DESC, "ModificationDate" DESC 
      LIMIT 1;
    -- ServiceThree
    SELECT INTO serviceThree "ID", "InspectionDate", "StatusID", "ServiceProceduresID"  FROM "ServiceThree" 
      WHERE "DeviceID" = device."ID" AND "Revoke" = FALSE AND "DeletionDate" IS NULL
      ORDER BY "InspectionDate" DESC, "ModificationDate" DESC 
      LIMIT 1;
    -- ServiceFour
    SELECT INTO serviceFour "ID", "CleaningDate" FROM "ServiceFour" 
      WHERE "DeviceID" = device."ID" AND "Revoke" = FALSE AND "DeletionDate" IS NULL
      ORDER BY "CleaningDate" DESC, "ModificationDate" DESC 
      LIMIT 1;

    -- INSERTING DATA
    INSERT INTO "LastService" (
      "ID", "DeviceID", "CreationDate", "ModificationDate",
      "SCBATestID", "SCBATestDate", "SCBATestStatus", "SCBAServiceType",
      "InspectionID", "InspectionDate", "InspectionStatus", "InspectionServiceType",
      "CylinderTestID", "CylinderTestDate",
      "CleaningID", "CleaningDate"
    ) VALUES (
      uuid_generate_v4(), device."ID", now(), now(),
      serviceOne."ID", serviceOne."ExecutionDate", serviceOne."ResultSuccessful", '00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000001',
      serviceThree."ID", serviceThree."InspectionDate", serviceThree."StatusID", serviceThree."ServiceProceduresID",
      serviceTwo."ID", serviceTwo."ExecutionDate",
      serviceFour."ID", serviceFour."CleaningDate"
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT set_DeviceLastServiceDate();
```

TRIED SOME SOLUTIONS https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/7-best-practice-tips-postgresql-bulk-data-loading
Set all used tables to `SET UNLOGGED` & `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the insert procedure from a loop to a single query? Also: what indexes do these tables have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.